# Catch stdErr output in golang

Tags: go

I have written a go program to monitor some MySQL databases.

In the following example, I simply display "Connection Success!" when the connection is successful or "Connection Error:" followed by the error message in case of failure.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    err := mysqlConnect()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Connection Error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Connection Success!")
    }
}

func mysqlConnect() error {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "myuser:mypwd@tcp(10.2.0.3:3306)/mysql")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

This works as expected, but in some cases, some error message appears while executing db.Ping() and is displayed to stdErr:

For example:

```
$ go run main.go
[mysql] 2019/07/22 18:01:59 auth.go:293: unknown auth plugin:dialog
Connection Error: this authentication plugin is not supported
```

The last line is my expected message, but the previous line is displayed when calling db.Ping().

I would like to catch/hide this message `[mysql] 2019/07/22 18:01:59 auth.go:293: unknown auth plugin:dialog`, as I already gets a clean error message that I can handle as I wish (displaying it or not).

How can I prevent such an error message from appearing (in code I mean, not at the calling time)?

Comment: It looks like that mysql driver is calling `log` directly, which libraries generally should never do. Unfortunately there is not a lot you can do to prevent that in a single, third-party function call, short of forking the library.

Comment: @Adrian It uses `errLog` which _defaults_ to some Logger but can be set manually: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/749ddf1598b47e3cd909414bda735fe790ef3d30/errors.go#L49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment by @tkausi suggests, you ought to set a custom logger for the `go-sql-driver` package with https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#SetLogger

Your custom logger can then do whatever makes sense for your application, including "swallowing" these logging statements and not displaying anything in case of no errors.

---

To answer the question's title, you can capture `os.Stderr` with something like this:

```
func doPrint() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "output")
}

func main() {
    old := os.Stderr
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stderr = w

    doPrint()

    w.Close()
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&buf, r)
    os.Stderr = old

    fmt.Println("Captured:", buf.String())
}
```

Comment: That's it! For my case, Implementing a custom logger with `mysql.SetLogger` as described in this issue: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/956#issuecomment-487807780 did the job. thanks